# How can I use XAML Buttons to enter an expression into a NumberBox object? (C++/XAML)

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-c++, uwp

I'm creating an UWP calculator using **C++** and **XAML** (Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10). I've created a NumberBox object, and I want to make my buttons enter their value into the Object. I've tried to associate them some accelerator functions (es. button 1 = ASCII `1`) and set as their Click functions the Accelerator ID.

My (Sample) code (MainPage.xaml.cpp):

```
    int MainPage::Button_Click_1()
    {
        return CW_1; // Returns number 1
    }
```

Unfortunately, when i press the button, the NumberBox object deselects itself so the Button cannot insert its value.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**
For anyone who has the same problem, I found way to make it work.
It's an ugly method, but it works: I've created some variables (respectively `double num1 = 0'`, `char sym = 'N'` and `num2 = 0`) and I made the `<NumberBox>` Object (`x:Name="NumBox1"`) operate with them. Then I created a `<TextBox>` Object (`x:Name="SymVisualizer"`) which visualizes the symbol in case of success or the string `"err"` in case of syntax error.

Here there is a sample `<Button>` code (which inserts a number into the box):

```
int ProjectName::MainPage::Button_Click_1(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (SymVisualizer->Text == "err")    // Clears the TextBox content if the previous expression gave an error
    {
        SymVisualizer->Text = "";
    }

    if (sym == 'N')    // If the symbol isn't set, the value is assigned to num1
    {
        if (num1 != NumBox1->Value && NumBox1->Value > 0)    // Syncronizes the NumBerBox value with num1
        {
            num1 = NumBox1->Value;
        }

        if (((num1 * 10) + 1) > 999999999999)    // If inserting a number will create an error (due to "double" type capability), the number will not be inserted
        {

        }
        else    // If inserting a number doesn't create any problem, inserts the number
        {
            num1 = (num1 * 10) + 1;    // Slides the digits and adds 1
        }

        NumBox1->Value = num1;    // Shows num1 as NumberBox Value
    }

    if (sym == '+' || sym == '-' || sym == '*' || sym == '/')    // If the symbol is set, the value is assigned to num2
    {
        if (num2 != NumBox1->Value && NumBox1->Value > 0)    // Synchronizes the NumBerBox value with num1
        {
            num2 = NumBox1->Value;
        }

        if (((num2 * 10) + 1) > 999999999999)    // If inserting a number will create an error (due to "double" type capability), the number will not be inserted
        {

        }
        else    // If inserting a number doesn't create any problem, inserts the number
        {
            num2 = (num2 * 10) + 1;    // Slides the digits and adds 1
        }

        NumBox1->Value = num2;    // Shows num1 as NumberBox Value
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here there is a sample `<Button>` code (which inserts the symbol into the box):

```
char ProjectName::MainPage::Button_Click_Plus(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (sym == 'N' && num1 != 0)    // If sym value is unchanged and num1 is different from 0, sets the symbol
    {
        num1 = NumBox1->Value;    // Synchronizes num1 with NumberBox value
        sym = '+';    // Sets the symbol
        SymVisualizer->Text = "+";    // Shows the symbol in the TextBox Object
        NumBox1->Value = num2;    // Shows num2's value (which is 0 at this point)
    }

    if ((sym == '+' || sym == '-' || sym == '*' || sym == '/'), num1 == 0)    // If the symbol is already set, does nothing
    {
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And finally, the `<Button>`  that calculates and shows the result (I created some functions like `Addition()`, `Subtraction()`, `Multiplication()` and `Division()` which are made for calculating the result):

```
int ProjectName::MainPage::Button_Click_Eql(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    double FinRes;    // The variable which contains the result
    bool UnsCal;    // A boolean value which indicates an unsupported expression (if set to true)

    num2 = NumBox1->Value;    // Synchronizes num2's value with NumberBox's value

    if(sym != '+' && sym != '-' && sym != '*' && sym != '/')    // If the symbol isn't supported, UnsCal value is set to true
    {
        UnsCal = true;
    }

    if (sym == '+')    // If the symbol is '+', executes an addition
    {
        FinRes = Addition(num1, num2);
        UnsCal = false;
    }

    if (sym == '-')    // If the symbol is '-', executes a subtraction
    {
        FinRes = Subtraction(num1, num2);
        UnsCal = false;
    }

    if (sym == '*')    // If the symbol is '+', executes a mutiplication
    {
        FinRes = Multiplication(num1, num2);
        UnsCal = false;
    }

    if (sym == '/')    // If the symbol is '/', executes a division
    {
        if (num2 != 0)    // If num2 isn't 0, the result is valid.
        {
            FinRes = Division(num1, num2);
            UnsCal = false;
        }
        
        if (num2 == 0)    // If num2 is 0, the result is unsupported (is impossible to divide for 0)
        {
            

            UnsCal = true;    // Identifies the expression as unsupported
        }
    }

    if (!UnsCal)    // If UnsCal value is false (which means that the expression is supported) shows the result
    {
        SymVisualizer->Text = "";    // Clears the TextBox Object
        NumBox1->Value = FinRes;    // Shows the result as NumberBox's value

        num1 = 0;    // Clears num1's value
        sym = 'N';    // Clears sym's value
        num2 = 0;    // Clears num2's value
    }
    else    // If UnsCal is true (the expression is unsupported) gives error
    {
        num1 = 0;    // Clears num1's value
        sym = 'N';    // Clears sym's value
        num2 = 0;    // Clears num2's value

        NumBox1->Value = num1;    // Restarts the calculation by showing 0 (num1's actual value) on NumberBox
        SymVisualizer->Text = "err";    // Says that there was a syntax error
    }

    

    return 0;
}
```

I hope that this can be useful to someone (sorry for the bad English, it's not my main language) and thanks for given answers.

Comment: It's not good practice to display  expression with nuberbox, please refer this official [calculator](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator) open source .

Comment: Thanks, I found out in that page C++/CX examples too...
But they aren't apparently working: I'm trying to use a ```<Run>``` object and show in it a calculated variable... Will it work?

_Sorry if I am not so good, I'm a beginner_

Comment: You can try to walk the visual tree and inject text into the underlying textbox but this is a bad practice. Since the NumberBox control is only designed to display Numbers, I'm not sure if this is the right control for this. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Do you only want to inject numbers or operators too?